# What is this plastic strip inside my laminate flooring?

Tags: flooring, installation, laminate

I'm installing this laminate flooring and noticed a plastic stirp in the groove of each plank. What is it for and should it stay where it is or be removed during the installation?

Laminate brand: Kronotex Raven Ridge Estate Grey Oak

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The 5G locking system uses a set of plastic clips on the inside of the
> groove to hold the attached plank in place. You will hear a slight
> audible click when you’ve installed the planks correctly. See the
> installation video demo below for a visualization of how to install a
> 5G locking system flooring.
>
> https://www.bestlaminate.com/blog/the-difference-between-5g-and-megaloc-locking-systems/

> The panels use a tongue-and-groove “Clic” system that lets you simply
> snap panels together...
>
> https://m.kronotex.com/Laminate-Flooring-Guide/Installing-snap-together-laminate-flooring-1419384348.html